# Next.js 14 & cached fetch

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am fetching content from Contentful's API to server up in my page.tsx files. It works perfectly except for the fact that its over cached. The data I'm trying to pull is RARELY going to be changed, so that works fine. But in development modes I'd like for it to pull new data everytime.

I've modified the headers in fetch to try to adjust for it, but doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Thoughts?

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEVMODE === "true"
  ? {
      headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
        Pragma: "no-cache",
        Expires: "0",
        CacheControl: "no-cache",
      },
    }
  : {};
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers you've defined should prevent caching responses when process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEVMODE is set to "true". However, you need to make sure that you include these headers in each fetch request.

Updated code example:

```
const headers = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEVMODE === "true"
  ? {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
      Pragma: "no-cache",
      Expires: "0",
      CacheControl: "no-cache",
    }
  : {};

fetch(yourAPIEndpoint, {
  headers: headers,
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    // PROCESS YOUR DATA HERE
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Fetch error:", error);
  });
```